# entrust delete() error Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, entrust

i use below code for remove one record from roles table:

```
if ( $role = Role::find($id)) {
    $role->delete();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'operation was successful.']);
}
```

but, an error happen and the message is:

**Class name must be a valid object or a string**

i google it!, for some answer i had to say config/entrust.php file exist.

Comment: find() method work and i can see the result.

Comment: Are you sure message is emitted by these lines?

Answer (score 2):

delete() method dos not work on Role Model, in this situation for delete one record or one role after find for exp Role::whereId($id)->delete(); work for me and my problem solved for no.

Answer (score 2):

Add this method in Role model:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Config::get('auth.providers.users.model'),
        Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'),
        Config::get('entrust.role_foreign_key'),
        Config::get('entrust.user_foreign_key')
    );
}
```